# How ABP generate IRepository<TEntity> for Entity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to understand how ABP does the above.

The normal workflow in ABP is:

1. Add the entity class inheriting from Entity based class to the Core
   project
2. Add the DbSet to the context in EFCore project
3. Add a new IEntityAppService interface and implementation to Application project
4. In the IEntityAppService implementation inject the IRepository to the constructor
5. Enjoy!!

What I have done to try to understand:

1. I have looked at the Abp source code and got the impression that this is being done by Open Generics between `IRepository<T>` and `EfCoreRepositoryBase<T>` with Factory magic. However, I tried to do this in AspNetCore DI with:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       // Add framework services.
       // adding DbContext
       // adding Mvc etc....

       // RepositoryBase => like EfCoreRepositoryBase in ABP
       // Error on this line, DI can not instantiate RepositoryBase as it is abstract
       services.AddTransient<IRepository<>, RepositoryBase<>);
   }
   ```

Please can someone explain the mechanism to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic is in [`EfGenericRepositoryRegistrar.cs`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/1ca41db6c0f502c42e92e004f1bab6d9784baf0f/src/Abp.EntityFramework.Common/Repositories/EfGenericRepositoryRegistrar.cs) where:

```
foreach (var entityTypeInfo in _dbContextEntityFinder.GetEntityTypeInfos(dbContextType))
{
    // ...

    iocManager.IocContainer.Register(
        Component
            .For(genericRepositoryType)
            .ImplementedBy(implType)
            .Named(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))
            .LifestyleTransient()
}
```

Note that [`EfCoreRepositoryBaseOfTEntityAndTPrimaryKey.cs`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/530e90600a3ff6489103286648340ce08f65b9a0/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/Repositories/EfCoreRepositoryBaseOfTEntityAndTPrimaryKey.cs) is not abstract.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will certainly have a look at this class.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to create custom repository. Look document at:

[Create custom repository](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EntityFramework-Integration#custom-repository-example)

And you can replace default repository of application like this:

```
[AutoRepositoryTypes(
    typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(IRepository<,>),
    typeof(SimpleTaskSystemEfRepositoryBase<>),
    typeof(SimpleTaskSystemEfRepositoryBase<,>)
)]
public class SimpleTaskSystemDbContext : AbpDbContext
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really just want to understand how it works.

Comment: yup, just give you some info, happy coding day :d